# How do I instantiate this enum ? The second statement does not compile

Tags: rust

```
enum X{
    None,
    Option(i64)
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let x = X::None;  // this is fine
    let y = X::Some(Some(None));   // this does not compile
}
```

How do I use this enum ?  The compiler doesn't like anything I've tried, and I think it might be related to the enum definition rather than the use of it.

Comment: Your second option is called X::Option, not X::Some, and it contains a i64, not an Option<i64>.

Comment: It's not clear what you expect the last statement to do. What is `X::Some`? You seem to be confusing `X` and `std::Option`.

Comment: I want to assign None to the second enum member.

Comment: How do you expect to assign None to an enum member taking a i64?

Answer (score 1):

```rust
enum X{
    None,
    Option(i64)
}

fn main() {
    let x = X::None;  // this is fine
    let y = X::Some(Some(None));   // this does not compile
}
```

The last line is meaningless. You are trying to construct an instance of X using X::Some, which isn't defined at all.
A semantically correct definition for an X that can be None or `Option<i64>` is as follows:

```rust
enum X {
    None,
    Some(Option<i64>),
}

fn main() {
    let x = X::None;
    let y = X::Some(None);
}
```

Comment: That's it !  The error was in the enum declaration.  Thanks Ivan.